# File uploads through PHP into MySQL database failing on larger files

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, mysqli

I hope someone here can point me in the right direction. I tried searching the forums, but found nothing on the subject.

Anyways... I'm using my site to upload files with PHP into the MySQL database. This all works fine, except when the files get somewhere in the ~4.5Mb and up range, the script fails. MySQL returns no error, and gives 0 for the insert id, and PHP gives no error.

I've tried the following in my php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
post_max_size = 15M
upload_max_filesize = 15M
memory_limit = -1
```

I've set max_allowed_packet size in MySQL:

```
Variable_name           Value
max_allowed_packet   16777216
```

and the column type for the file content is mediumblob

And here is the PHP code doing the upload, shortened a bit to exclude non-relevant stuff:

```
...
$con->query("SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 16777216;");
$con->autocommit(FALSE);
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$sql_query->bind_param('ssisb', $FILE['FILE_NAME'], $FILE['FILE_DESC'], $FILE['FILE_SIZE'],
$FILE['FILE_TYPE'], $null);
while(!feof($fp)){$sql_query->send_long_data(4, fread($fp, 8192));}
fclose($fp);
$sql_query->execute();
$fileIDs[$fileIndex] = $sql_query->insert_id;
...
$con->commit();
...
```

This is in a loop since you can upload multiple files through this, and even doing that works fine as long as the files are individually under ~4.5Mb

Does anybody here know why this might be happening, or any other way I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Change to and restart apache

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

also try adding the below lines in the my.cnf and restart

```
[mysqld]
# Performance settings used for import.
delay_key_write=ALL
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
```

Comment: I'm trying the post_max_size and upload_file_size right now, will know in a few minutes. Why would it have to be 100M if the files are failing at 4.5Mb and it's currently at 15?
Also, I don't have access to my.cnf on my webhost. I ssh'd in and looked everywhere for it.

Comment: Currently, it's `memory_limit = -1`, which should give it unlimited, no?

Comment: yes set in php script like this ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); or in php.ini as memory_limit = 64M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84022/discussion-between-chandran-and-neilsimp1).